# Neighbourhood of certain point in H is homeomorphic to image in modular curve (Diamond & Shurman 2.2.1)

Tags: number-theory, complex-geometry, modular-forms

I am trying to solve exercise 2.2.1 in Diamond and Shurman:

*Let $\Gamma$ be a congruence subgroup of $SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, and $\pi:\mathcal{H}\to Y(\Gamma)$ the quotient map from the complex upper half plane to the corresponding modular curve. Let $\tau\in\mathcal{H}$ be a point fixed only by the identity transformation from $\Gamma$, i.e. $\pm I$. Show that $\tau$ has a neighbourhood $U$ such that $\pi|_U : U\to \pi(U)$ is a homeomorphism.*

The problem says to use Proposition 2.1.1, which is the following:

*For $\tau_1,\tau_2\in\mathcal{H}$, there exists respective neighbourhoods $U_1$, $U_2$ such that for all $\gamma\in SL_2(\mathbb{Z})$, if $\gamma(U_1)\cap U_2\neq \emptyset$ then $\gamma(\tau_1)=\tau_2$.*

I know that $\pi$ is surjective, continuous and open, so I just need to find a neighbourhood of $\tau$ on which it is injective. But I simply cannot find such a neighbourhood - all the applications of Proposition 2.1.1. I can think of requires me to intersect infinitely many neighbourhoods, so we aren't guaranteed the intersection is open. I do not think it is too hard, but for the life of me I cannot find the argument. Any hints appreciated.

Comment: Apply the proposition to $\tau_1=\tau_2=\tau$, and consider $U=U_1 \cap U_2$.

Comment: @Mindlack Yep, that solves it. Thank you so much, you have saved me a lot of frustration. Feel free to add it as an answer, and I will accept it.